# Question about the nlme setup/syntax R for nested repeated observations regression R

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, multiple-regression, assumptions

I'm looking to perform a nonlinear mixed effects regression.

Sample data:

```
data.frame("id" = 1:2, 
           "intervention" = c(rep("a",9),rep("b", 9)),
           "area" = 1:3,
           "dv" = sample(18, replace=TRUE))
```

- In the sample data there were 3 observations per area and per intervention but the actually data isn't balanced like that.
- DV is continuous data
- 2 subjects with repeated observations

I know from [R Companion](https://rcompanion.org/rcompanion/d_07.html) that I can use the following code to nest 1 level

```
library(nlme)

model = lme(dv ~ intervention, random=~1|id,
            data=Data,
            method="REML")
```

How do I nest a second level to also account for area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `lme` fits linear mixed models, not non-linear ones. For certain types of non-linear mixed models, you can use `nlme`.
2. If `area` is nested in the levels of `id`, you can use the code

```
model = lme(dv ~ intervention, random=~1|id/area,
            data=Data,
            method="REML")
```

to fit the nested mixed effects model.

Edits:

If you just specify `random = ~ 1|id`, you fit the single-level mixed model, which corresponds to the regression equation

$$
\textrm{dv}_{ik} =  \beta_0 + \beta_1 \textbf{1}_{\textrm{intervention}} + b_i + \epsilon_{ik} \\
b_i \sim \textrm{Normal} (0, \sigma_b^2) \\
\epsilon_{ik} \sim \textrm{Normal} (0, \sigma^2),
$$

where $b_i$ are the random effects due to differences among patients.

Nesting further with `random = ~1 | id/area`, then the effect of the intervention is further conditional on the random `area` effects that vary *within* patients (id's). This is basically the same as conditioning effects on the interaction of `area` and `id`. The regression equation in the nested model is

$$
\textrm{dv}_{ijk} =  \beta_0 + \beta_1 \textbf{1}_{\textrm{intervention}} + b_i + b_{ij} + \epsilon_{ijk} \\
b_i \sim \textrm{Normal} (0, \sigma_b^2) \\
b_{ij} \sim \textrm{Normal} (0, \sigma_c^2) \\
\epsilon_{ijk} \sim \textrm{Normal} (0, \sigma^2),
$$

where $b_i$ is the same as above, but now we additionally have $b_{ij}$, which are random effects due to `area`s *within* patient. (Some may prefer to use the notation $b_{i(j)}$ to make it clear that the effects are not crossed).

If there is further nesting, then (I think) the syntax extends the way you would expect it to: `random = ~ 1 | id/area/subarea`, but we are now pushing the limits of my experience with `nlme`.

Comment: The intervention is applied multiple times within an area for a given subject. The intervention is applied across multiple areas. What's the logic behind the id/area? What if I wanted to take it a level deeper and there's a subarea? Thanks!

Comment: @myfatson check my edits and report back.

Comment: Beautifully explained! What do you use to perform post-hoc testing on a double-nested model like this?

Comment: What would you like to know, post-hoc? The library `emmeans` has a lot of post-hoc testing capabilities, so does `survival::yates`.